# Jupyter Tensorflow GPU Crash

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Hello there I'm trying to fit my CNN model in Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

> '/device:GPU:0' (OUTPUT)

When I try to fit like that;

```py
with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    model.fit(
        trainx,
        testx,
        epochs=50,
        batch_size=90,
        validation_data=(trainy, testy),
        callbacks=[early],
    )
```

I'm getting this error

```py
[I 21:07:52.519 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c27c1e21-aafc-4682-bd3c-13ae7ce30d2a, name: python3
[W 21:07:52.560 NotebookApp] No session ID specified
2022-05-01 21:08:02.707956: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-05-01 21:08:03.097364: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5970 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
[I 21:08:16.496 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
WARNING:root:kernel c27c1e21-aafc-4682-bd3c-13ae7ce30d2a restarted
[I 21:08:27.141 NotebookApp] Interrupted...
[I 21:08:27.141 NotebookApp] Shutting down 1 kernel
[I 21:08:27.142 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: c27c1e21-aafc-4682-bd3c-13ae7ce30d2a
[I 21:08:27.373 NotebookApp] Shutting down 0 terminals
```

How can I solve this or what's the reason of this error, any idea & comments?

Comment: is it happening right after you run that _fit_ command or after some time? That is very hard to say just by looking that _error log_ but that can come from memory leak based on my previous experience with tensorflow. Based on when it happens, maybe we can have better understanding.

Comment: It happens right after the *fit* method. I also tried to do without *Jupyter Notebook*, but it happened again.

Comment: If you want I can post url of the notebook too.

Comment: Are you able to fit another model? For instance when you try to fit https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate, are you able to do that? If not, that is probably related with installation. If that is working and your code cause an issue, this means that there can be some memory leak in your code.

Comment: yeah I fit the [model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) within the 5 seconds

Comment: I see. So then your installation should be correct. Possibly your model has some memory leak. Can you try to fit with using small percentage of the train and test data? I am not sure how the look like but maybe just try with 10 sample from train and 10 sample from test and see what is going on. If that fits, maybe you can increase the sample sizes and until having same issue. Probably if we can see that, that would be helpful to understand what is wrong.

Comment: my [code](https://github.com/BestSithInEU/Skin_Cancer/blob/master/option_1.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Just to test, can you set batch size to 10 to see what will happen?

Comment: same, kernel dies

Comment: Which CPU are you using to run this?

Comment: original [notebook](https://github.com/Lokeshrathi/Skin-Cancer-Classification/blob/master/skin-cancer-classification.ipynb)

Comment: CPU AMD Ryzen 7 3800XT & RTX 2080 is my GPU